# command line pipe syntax on terminal

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, terminal, pipe

I'm executing following commands in a nodejs application using child processes.

1. `which zip` to get path of the zip executable
2. `path-to-zip  + " -r abc.zip " + path + " && du -hs abc.zip"` using ampersand `&&`

how can we chain these commands together to form one single command so that `path-to-zip` gets substituted from 1) `which zip`.

I'm using `which zip` to ensure path is correct, tell me if it's useless if the path `/usr/bin/zip` has been the same and going to be the same across linux and mac os, if that's the case then I'm better off with hardcoding the path in my application, please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on your shell.

`Bash` is the the most common shell in Linux distribution.

For `Bash`, there are two common ways which are called **Command Substitution** to achieve this.

1. `｀which zip｀ + whatever you want` (｀means`, I type ｀due to the syntax policy of StackOverflow.)
2. `$(which zip) + whatever you want`

> **Manual of Command Substitution** :
>
> https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html

Comment: okay, is `/usr/bin/zip` has been under the same path throughout history?

Comment: @user2727195: The answer is yes, the result of `which` will be decided based on your environment path.

Comment: so to understand it right, this hardcoded with path command `/usr/bin/zip -r abc.zip folder  && du -hs abc.zip` will work in all systems, I can choose not to use command substitution, right?

Comment: No, in your case `which` will find the `zip` based on your path, and getting `/usr/bin/zip`. However, you can not promise all system's `zip` command is in the same directory. For example in a FreeBSD system, `zip` is located in `/usr/local/bin/zip`, in this case, you should write `$(which zip)` to deploy this script in different system.